# Is there an Opera Browser extension that will press a button on a popup window

Tags: automation, browser-addons, opera

I have a webpage I visit frequently that has a chat room. After a few minutes of not typing anything it pops up a window specifiying that you have been idle and to hit a button the page to re-enable the page into an active state.

Is there an extension that can set to automagically press a button on a specified page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is some distinguishing thing about the window such as its title always contains something, you can use Autohotkey to send keystrokes to window.

Get Autohotkey here: [autohotkey.com](http://autohotkey.com)
And write this script

```
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetTimer, ChatRoomStayActive, 60000
ChatRoomStayActive:
IfWinNotActive, <chatroom_popup_window_title_here>
ControlSend, <chatroom_popup_window_title_here>, A
return
return
```

This will basically type A in the chatroom window every 60 seconds if its not active

Comment: If you need to click a specific button on that page, you can look into `ControlClick` for autohotkey

Comment: Basically the chatroom sits there and if you dont type for 10 minutes or so, a little popup comes up on the screen and says "You've been inactive, blah blah" it has not title though. But the button does have the text "I'm Back". Would autoit be able to deal with this?

Comment: Use their window spy to see if you can hook up onto something. btw, why wait till that message appears? just keep sending keystrokes to chat window to prevent that popup from occurring..

Comment: Worked perfectly that way. I figured out how to send the click to a relative coordinate in the window every 10 minutes or so. Thanks so much for the help, and the introduction to an amazing tool!

Comment: Yes. it indeed is amazing and quite powerful.